# How to transmit many digital signals between two systems powered by different power supplies

Tags: power-supply, voltage, level-shifting

I’ve run into problems with my project.I have two different power supplies and I’m trying to pass logic signals through the system as you can see in the picture.

[image: sketch]

I’m looking for an IC that could handle this job but So far I was unsuccessful finding it

I’ve run into parts such as SN74AVC1T45, but such a device connects both grounds together which would cost short circuit in my project.

I could also use digital isolators, But those are terribly expensive especially when I’m trying to make 20 of these bridges.

Comment: A galvanically separated coupler. It depends on protocol layer which one. "But those are terribly expensive" it's a matter of point of view.

Comment: For what reason can you not connect GND on both PSU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is an up-to 30 V voltage difference between the two grounds, it's better to use some sort of galvanic isolation between the two systems.

**Low to medium speeds (up to 10Mbps with some optoisolators)**

For instance you can use an optoisolator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuuv4E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Values are shown just as an example, and assume that you are using an optocoupler with a current transfer ratio (CTR) not much smaller than 100%.

**Higher speed (up to 150Mbps)**

If you need to go at very high speed (e.g. 100Mbps), you can also use an SiO<sub>2</sub>-isolation barrier based digital isolator, such as [ISO7710](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7710.pdf).

Unlike conventional optoisolators, they do not use an LED and a photodetector, but they transmit a signal through a capacitor, by OOK modulation.

[image]

However, they are more expensive with respect optoisolators, and you need also decoupling capacitors on both sides.

**How to reduce cost**

Instead of using 20 isolated channels, you can try to implement some parallel-to-serial conversion in the first system, and a serial-to-parallel conversion in the second system. In this way, you'll have to send just 3 signals: data, clock, and a frame/load/chip select signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjwmt7.png)</sup>

The Parallel-in serial-out (PISO) register converts your 20 parallel inputs to a single serial stream. The serial-input parallel-output performs the opposite operation.

When you pulse (low pulse in case of a 74xx165) the `PARALLEL_LOAD` signal, then you load the parallel datas into the PISO shift register. On each clock pulse, `DOUT` will reflect the value of the next parallel input. The clock and such `DOUT` is transmitted across the isolation system of your choice.

The SIPO register will receive the clock and the data value (**note! you might need to invert the received clock signal according to your PISO/SIPO clock edge sensitivity!**). After you have sent all the data bits, pulse the `OUTPUT_LOAD` signal, to update the outputs of your SIPO register.

If you have a microcontroller, then you can avoid the PISO register and connect the SPI outputs (clock, MOSI, and two GPIOs for `PARALLEL_LOAD` and `OUTPUT_LOAD`) lines to the isolator. You can also use a port expander instead of the SIPO register, but that would be an overkill, since you would use it just a mere SIPO register (typically cheaper and available from a number of manufacturers, so you are not stuck with just one).

NOTE: in the circuit diagram above GNDs and VDDs are not shown.